# Configure weak host validation on server-side TLS connection with Apple Secure Transport

Tags: c, ssl, secure-transport

I want to write a server that (purely for testing!!) allows a client to connect with a cert that includes an invalid hostname. I'm using Apple's Secure Transport API in C on Mac OS X. I set up a server connection like:

```
SSLContextRef ssl_ctx_ref = SSLCreateContext (kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                              kSSLServerSide,
                                              kSSLStreamType);

SSLSetClientSideAuthenticate (ssl_ctx_ref, kTryAuthenticate);
```

With this in place, if the client presents a certificate with an invalid hostname, `SSLHandshake` fails with errSSLClosedAbort (-9806).

Passing `kNeverAuthenticate` instead of `kTryAuthenticate` allows an invalid client cert.

**Questions:**

- Is `SSLSetClientSideAuthenticate` the right function to be using for this purpose -- for enabling weak hostname validation for client certificates?
- If so, they why doesn't `kTryAuthenticate` do so, why must I use `kNeverAuthenticate`?